# *ngFor shows element in empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Following *ngFor

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#todo of todoService.todos">
    {{todo}}
  <li>
</ul>
```

Where todoService is an Injected Interface

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
    todos = []
}
```

When I load the page, the output is `<li></li>` instead of nothing.

Any idea why? Since the array is empty, there shouldn't be a `<li>`-tag

**EDIT**
It's also occuring when I initialize the array with values. There is always a **trailing** empty element for no reason.

**EDIT2**
Example of the problem
https://plnkr.co/edit/MRYC4MHtlDLfBMUPsL6o?p=preview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah yes :) you can stare blind at problems like these, even though the solution is sometimes too simple.

I believe you would like the bottom `<li>` to be a closing tag? That might just fix your issue:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#todo of todoService.todos">
    {{todo}}
  </li>  <!-- this nagger right here -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem with beta1:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <div>
      Test:
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#l of service.list">{{l}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private service:Service) {

  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/hGpCIZQghtMBbpplV9tV?p=preview.

Which version of Angular2 did you use?

Thierry

Comment: I'm actually also confused because I'm following a tutorial (not the quickstart), but I use the quickstart boilerplate from google with   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0", and your sample proves me wrong.. I'm trying to find the reason